# No Sound and other issues with porting Qt project to Mac

Tags: macos, qt, audio, porting, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to port this project over to Mac OSX 10.8.5, it was originally designed and tested on Windows Vista and Windows 7 and I've strictly stuck to the Qt framework.

https://github.com/wiseguy12851/AlarmClock

After compiling with Qt Creator 5.1.1 using clang compiler, I ran the project in debug mode and got a lot of weird errors before the application launched.

```
objc[3522]: Class AVFCaptureFramesDelegate is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class AVFMediaRecorderDelegate is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class AVFCameraSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class AVFMediaPlayerSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class TransparentQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class HiddenQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3522]: Class QTMovieObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

When the application launched I noticed a few oddities in the way some things were aligned or layed out which is normal and can usually easily be fixed but upon testing the sound output nothing played. I then went to debug and see if the sound method was being called and found out it was but nothing was playing.

The debug also gave out a ton of error and/or warning messages as well right before launching, the below was all the messages in one debug right-before launch.

```
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/minimal/.obj/debug-shared/main.o" - no debug information available for "main.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/minimal/.obj/debug-shared/qminimalintegration.o" - no debug information available for "qminimalintegration.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/minimal/.obj/debug-shared/qminimalbackingstore.o" - no debug information available for "qminimalbackingstore.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(qunixeventdispatcher.o)" - no debug information available for "eventdispatchers/qunixeventdispatcher.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(qgenericunixeventdispatcher.o)" - no debug information available for "eventdispatchers/qgenericunixeventdispatcher.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(moc_qunixeventdispatcher_qpa_p.o)" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_qunixeventdispatcher_qpa_p.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/offscreen/.obj/debug-shared/main.o" - no debug information available for "main.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/offscreen/.obj/debug-shared/qoffscreenintegration.o" - no debug information available for "qoffscreenintegration.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/offscreen/.obj/debug-shared/qoffscreenwindow.o" - no debug information available for "qoffscreenwindow.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/offscreen/.obj/debug-shared/qoffscreencommon.o" - no debug information available for "qoffscreencommon.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/offscreen/.obj/debug-shared/qoffscreenintegration_dummy.o" - no debug information available for "qoffscreenintegration_dummy.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(qunixeventdispatcher.o)" - no debug information available for "eventdispatchers/qunixeventdispatcher.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(qgenericunixeventdispatcher.o)" - no debug information available for "eventdispatchers/qgenericunixeventdispatcher.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a(moc_qunixeventdispatcher_qpa_p.o)" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_qunixeventdispatcher_qpa_p.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfcameraserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for "avfcameraserviceplugin.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfcameracontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfcameracontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideorenderercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideorenderercontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfcamerametadatacontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfcamerametadatacontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfimagecapturecontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfimagecapturecontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediarecordercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediarecordercontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfcameraservice.o" - no debug information available for "avfcameraservice.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfcamerasession.o" - no debug information available for "avfcamerasession.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfstoragelocation.o" - no debug information available for "avfstoragelocation.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideodevicecontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideodevicecontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/avfaudioinputselectorcontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfaudioinputselectorcontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/camera/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfcameraserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfcameraserviceplugin.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediaplayercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediaplayercontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediaplayermetadatacontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediaplayermetadatacontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediaplayerservice.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediaplayerservice.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediaplayerserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediaplayerserviceplugin.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfmediaplayersession.o" - no debug information available for "avfmediaplayersession.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideorenderercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideorenderercontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfdisplaylink.o" - no debug information available for "avfdisplaylink.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideoframerenderer.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideoframerenderer.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideowidgetcontrol.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideowidgetcontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/avfvideowidget.o" - no debug information available for "avfvideowidget.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayercontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayermetadatacontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayermetadatacontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayersession.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayersession.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayerserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfmediaplayerserviceplugin.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfvideorenderercontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfvideorenderercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfdisplaylink.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfdisplaylink.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/.obj/debug-shared/moc_avfvideowidgetcontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_avfvideowidgetcontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7backend.o" - no debug information available for "qt7backend.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7serviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for "qt7serviceplugin.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7movieviewoutput.o" - no debug information available for "qt7movieviewoutput.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7movierenderer.o" - no debug information available for "qt7movierenderer.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7ciimagevideobuffer.o" - no debug information available for "qt7ciimagevideobuffer.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qcvdisplaylink.o" - no debug information available for "qcvdisplaylink.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7movieviewrenderer.o" - no debug information available for "qt7movieviewrenderer.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7movievideowidget.o" - no debug information available for "qt7movievideowidget.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7playercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "mediaplayer/qt7playercontrol.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7playermetadata.o" - no debug information available for "mediaplayer/qt7playermetadata.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7playerservice.o" - no debug information available for "mediaplayer/qt7playerservice.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/qt7playersession.o" - no debug information available for "mediaplayer/qt7playersession.mm".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/moc_qt7videooutput.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_qt7videooutput.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qt7/.obj/debug-shared/moc_qt7serviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_qt7serviceplugin.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audioencodercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "audioencodercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiocontainercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "audiocontainercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiomediarecordercontrol.o" - no debug information available for "audiomediarecordercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audioinputselector.o" - no debug information available for "audioinputselector.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiocaptureservice.o" - no debug information available for "audiocaptureservice.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiocaptureserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for "audiocaptureserviceplugin.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiocapturesession.o" - no debug information available for "audiocapturesession.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/audiocaptureprobecontrol.o" - no debug information available for "audiocaptureprobecontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audioencodercontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audioencodercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiocontainercontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiocontainercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiomediarecordercontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiomediarecordercontrol.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audioinputselector.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audioinputselector.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureservice.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureservice.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureserviceplugin.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureserviceplugin.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiocapturesession.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiocapturesession.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/audiocapture/.obj/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureprobecontrol.o" - no debug information available for ".moc/debug-shared/moc_audiocaptureprobecontrol.cpp".
objc[3570]: Class AVFCaptureFramesDelegate is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class AVFMediaRecorderDelegate is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class AVFCameraSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class AVFMediaPlayerSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class TransparentQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class HiddenQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[3570]: Class QTMovieObserver is implemented in both /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/***/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtsvg/src/plugins/iconengines/svgiconengine/.obj/debug-shared/main.o" - no debug information available for "main.cpp".
Could not find object file "/Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-LGPLRELEASEBUILD510-OSX106/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtsvg/src/plugins/iconengines/svgiconengine/.obj/debug-shared/qsvgiconengine.o" - no debug information available for "qsvgiconengine.cpp".
```

I can't for the life of me figure out all this, also any code referencing can be done with the github link.

.pro file below

```
cache()

#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-10-28T05:20:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AlarmClock
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        windowmain.cpp

HEADERS  += windowmain.h

FORMS    += windowmain.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

OTHER_FILES += \
    Alarm.rc

win32:RC_FILE += Alarm.rc
```

Heres kind of a minimum of what I'm trying to do

.h file:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
...
QMediaPlayer* player;
```

.cpp file:

```
player(new QMediaPlayer(this)),
...
player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:///sound"));
...
player->play();
```

It should be noted that it works on Windows perfectly, I think Qt's messing up the compile on my mac

Comment: Do the warnings go away in release mode?

Comment: Also, try provide a minimal example instead of linking to github.

Comment: Yes it does the same thing in release mode. I'll be happy to give a minimal example but I'm not sure what you mean since the file is fairly large and it won't make much sense to give out a method or 2 in it.

Comment: I added the bits where the sound is mentioned in my program as a minimum example, is this what you were talking about a minimum example?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the error message, which isn't so weird if you read it carefully. Just take the first line and compare the paths that states that: -

> Class AVFCaptureFramesDelegate is implemented in both...
>
> libqavfcamera.dylib and libqavfcamera_**debug**.dylib

So you've got a mixture of both release and debug versions of libraries being linked, which is likely to account for the things you're seeing misaligned. Sort this out and the errors will go away and your sound should return.

Comment: I've tried sorting it out, I can' find anything at all on Google on 2 libraries being linked, I've triple checked all the build arguments and everything. Everything looks good and nothing seems to work. I get the same errors for both Debug and Release. Upon clearing out all the contents of the release or debug folder it throws in another complaint that this version of OSX isn't supported which I find very hard to believe since I'm running osx 10.8.5 and Qt says clang supports 10.6 and up. I am completely lost.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your .pro to the question?

Comment: I downloaded your project from gibhub (looking good!). After removing the the line "greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets" from the .pro, it builds fine for me and runs, but I do not hear any sound. One thing I notice is that you have the sound file in the resource. Unless it's changed for Qt 5, loading audio files from resources never used to work.

Comment: Also note, that in connecting the error signal from player and then getting the error with player->errorString(), it states that the media file is not found when trying to load it.

Comment: Are you testing the sound on Mac or Windows, on Windows the sound plays just fine for me, and for that I never thought of testing for the error, on Mac I never thought about testing for error cause there were a million errors. Thanks I'll test out and see if I get the same error but what do I do about all the other errors.

Comment: I'm testing on OSX with Qt Creator. It may be worthwhile you trying that and recreating the project with a new project file.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I've deleted and recreated the .user settings for the mac project cleared out completely the compile directories and tried everything I could think of. It still has all those exact compile and run errors and it can't play the alarm sound. I did confirm that it shows "file not found" but tried numerous solutions all ending with the same file not found error.

Comment: Have you tried an audio file that isn't in the resource and using its full path?

Comment: I have tried that but not with full path, I tried with relative paths. Later on today I'll try it with a full path and post if it works or not. Did you get all those errors when you compiled it, are they to be expected?

Comment: Relative paths in OSX is not so simple. When you run the app, you're actually running the binary inside the bundle at AlarmClock.app/Contents/MacOS/AlarmClock, so you'd need to find out what the current working directory is first. Yes I happened to get the same complaint of mixed debug and release libraries - very strange. I didn't get the other errors of the missing object files.

Comment: Yes it still doesnt load with same error message, I pasted the music file into the Music folder in my home directory and it still won't load giving off the same error message. I've tried file:// with QUrl, and QUrl::fromLocalFile with file://, without file://, and without any starting slash. No matter what I try it still gives off same message. I tried playing the alarm anyways thinking it's an incorrect error message but it definitely doesn't play.

Comment: Then I expect it's what I originally stated; the problem is the mixed dlls. If I get time, I'll take another look.